# Reset Pythonanywhere account

Tags: pythonanywhere

How do I reset completely my PythonAnywhere account, because I just get errors.

In my PythonAnywhere I have the following set up:

Source code: /home/myusername/repo-test-B/MY_file_B_repo_B.py

Working directory: /home/my username/repo-test-B

WSGI configuration file:/var/www/my username_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py

WSDI SETTINGS: I replaced the default with the actual directory.
I am pulling out my hair as I can not start over unless I reset, please help and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PythonAnywhere doesn't support automatic account reset (yet).  If you use a free account, just create another one (you can request deletion of the "broken" one, if you'd like to retain the same username); if you use a paid account, you can request the support team (use the feedback form) to reset it to defaults.